# how to Write a query to display emp details of the specific row?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can any one help me with the below query:

Display employee details from emp table whose rownum is 5.
when I try to write as "select * from emp where rownum=5" the output displayed is "no rows selected"

Comment: Just Dudu Markovitz sais in his answer: there simply is no record with rownum 5. So the assignment makes no sense.

Comment: This is explained in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no concept of "order" for rows in a table.
2. **rownum** is increased only when a row is being outputted so you can only use `rownum <= 5`